# Should the ID column be the first column of a table?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I have a table with a natural 5 columns primary key but I want to change that primary key into a unique key and I want to add an autoincrement integer clustered Primary Key.

Can I just add an ID column + clustered PK or should the ID column always be the first column of a table? I know that just adding will work but **I am afraid of performance issues.**

If the ID column should be the first then I have to do a data migration.

Comment: It does not have to be the first column

Comment: But what about performance?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18719/does-the-order-of-columns-in-a-tables-definition-matter

Comment: I don't understand people who creates `PK`s from 5 columns. In addition to fact that it is extremely unreadable, It is a bad idea if you have a big table with a lot of `FK`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter where is the PK column logically defined. However making it a clustered index will always put the column (physically) at the "beginning" because the index itself becomes the table, but this still won't affect performance as much as the data type and the ordering of the data.

A quote from "Beginning SQL Server 2008 for Developers" by Robin Dewson

> As previously stated, a clustered index actually keeps the data in the
>   table in a specific order. When you specify a column (or multiple
>   columns) as a clustered index, upon inserting a record, SQL Server
>   will place that record in a physical position to keep the records in
>   the correct ascending or descending order that corresponds to the
>   order defined in the index. To explain this a bit further, if you have
>   a clustered index on customer numbers; and the data currently has
>   customer numbers 10, 6, 4, 7, 2, and 5; then SQL Server will
>   physically store the data in the following order: 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10.
>   If a process then adds in a customer number 9, it will be physically
>   inserted between 7 and 10, which may mean that the record for customer
>   number 10 needs to move physically. Therefore, if you have defined a
>   clustered index on a column or a set of columns where data insertions
>   cause the clustered index to be reordered, this will greatly affect
>   your insert performance. SQL Server does provide a way to reduce the
>   reordering impact by allowing a fill factor to be specified when an
>   index is created.

Here is an interesting read with more info on the subject
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/

Answer (score 1):

Added this as comment, thought it might as well be an answer (at least till a better one comes along)

Like @juergend said, it's not necessary for a PK to be the first column. I'm currently working on a database where the PK's are always at the end of the tables. While this works, I find it helps visualising the data when the PK is at the front. This is probably just a personal preference, and you (and your employer) have to decide whether a migration is worth the effort. Performance is not touched at all by the ordinal position of the PK

Answer (score 1):

There is only one clustered key possible. The PK is - in most cases - the clustered key by default (but you may define even the PK as not clustered).

The difference: The clustered key creates a *physical* order of the rows.

You should never chose a column for clustering, where inserts are not in an implicit order (worst - but quite common - is the `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`). This will lead to bad fragmentation and bad performance even with other indexes which try to use the (bad performing) clustered index as lookup.

Your attempt to introduce an autoincrement column to play the role as clustered lookup is - for sure! - a good idea (as long as you don't want to allow offline inserts...).

To your questions:

- No, the position of the column is not important.
- as there is only one clustered key possible, you'll have to drop the existing (and re-create it as unique, but non clustered index)
- you should re-create all other indexes too after the new index exists, because they will then use your new clustered key as lookup.